# How is the law of karma valid when so many people from wealthy houses are unethical but to be born in those houses requires good karma?

Tags: karma

Growing up in school I would see bullies. Many of these bullies would be spoiled kids of rich parents. In fact, I've seen this trend where the more rich and affluent a family the more spoiled and insensitive their kids grow up to be.

You can even see examples of this among politicians, movie directors, the famous drunk driving kids of MLAs who get away with doing such evil things.

We typically say that the law of karma has caused such people to be born rich.

However, after being born so rich, these people have been committing crimes for decades in their lifetime while the poor people who grow up in a harsh environment turn out sensitive and caring?

We can see this pattern among world leaders as well who suppress their citizens and take away many of their freedom rights.

If you must do good deeds to get wealth and power in your next. We also say that the progress that you make towards dharma carries onto the next life. If that is true then how come so many people in wealthy families commit the worst of crimes?

TL;DR: People do lots of good deeds, get born in wealthy and powerful families. Then they do a lot of bad, insensitive things and end up harming lots of people in masses.

How have they made any progress in life if the law of karma is really valid here?

Comment: see Gita Chapter 16.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If karma works, why are so many evil or corrupted people successful?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8848/if-karma-works-why-are-so-many-evil-or-corrupted-people-successful)

Comment: @sv. I added some more clarity to my question. Hope it makes more sense now and the difference is clearer.

Comment: Even after your edits, I think it's a duplicate of several other questions, e.g., [How exactly does karma work?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-exactly-does-karma-work), [Why do bad things happen to good people?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9563/why-do-bad-things-happen-to-good-people) & [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-predetermined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma)

Comment: Let me summarize the question in one line. "Do good. Eventually born in rich / affluent family. Do bad." So you've actually come much backwards than starting point by doing good.

Comment: Your last sentence is important in this question, especially the if.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-predetermined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma)

Answer (score 1):

As per the law of Karma, you reap as you sow.

- Brihadarankya Upanishad

> स वा अयमात्मा ब्रह्म विज्ञानमयो मनोमयः प्राणमयश्चक्षुर्मयः श्रोत्रमयः पृथिवीमय आपोमयो वायुमय आकाशमयस्तेजोमयोऽतेजोमयः काममयोऽकाममयः क्रोधमयोऽक्रोधमयो धर्ममयोऽधर्ममयः सर्वमयस् श्रोत्रमयस् आकाशमयस् वायुमयस् तेजोमयस् आपोमयस् पृथिवीमयस् क्रोधमयस् अक्रोधमयस् हर्षमयस् अहर्षमयस् k श्रोत्रमयस् पृथिवीमयस् आपोमयस् वायुमयस् आकाशमयस् तेजोमयस् अतेजोमयस् काममयस् अकाममयस् क्रोधमयस् अक्रोधमयस् धर्ममयस् अधर्ममयस् सर्वमयः तद्यदेतदिदम्मयोऽदोमय इति यथाकारी यथाचारी तथा भवति । साधुकारी साधुर्भवति पापकारी पापो भवति पुण्यः पुण्येन कर्मणा भवति पापः पापेन । अथो खल्वाहुः काममय एवायं पुरुष इति स यथाकामो भवति तत्क्रतुर्भवति यत्क्रतुर्भवति तत्कर्म कुरुते यत्कर्म कुरुते तदभिसम्पद्यते ॥ ५ ॥
>
> IV-iv-5: That self is indeed Brahman, as also identified with the intellect, the Manas and the vital force, with the eyes and ears, with earth, water, air and the ether, with fire, and what is other than fire, with desire and the absence of desire, with anger and the absence of anger, with righteousness and unrighteousness, with everything --identified, in fact, with this (what is perceived) and with that (what is inferred). **As it does and acts, so it becomes; by doing good it becomes good, and by doing evil it becomes evil - it becomes virtuous through good acts and vicious through evil acts.** Others, however, say, 'The self is identified with desire alone. What it desires, it resolves; what it resolves, it works out; and **what it works out, it attains.'**

But the Karma of previous birth also affect the soul.

> 21. **The Karma, auspicious and inauspicious, done in many previous lives and preserved in seed forms, remains always inherent in a human soul.** Urged on by this Karma, the Jîvas quitting their previous bodies, enjoy Heaven or Hell as effects of these, their own acts.
>
> 22-23. **According to their good or bad works, the Jîvas acquire the higher happy body and enjoy various pleasures in the Heavens, or they take up very painful vicious bodies and suffer various pains in hell.**
>
> 24-25. At the expiry of the above period in Heaven or Hell, **when there comes the time of his assuming another body, the Jîva becomes conscious of the subtle body (Linga Deha) and takes his birth again. When the Linga Deha comes into existence, the part of the Karma done in various previous births that are ripe** and ready to yield their fruits, gets attached to the Jîva by God (or Destiny).
>
> 26. **Therefore the collective effect of Karma done in previous births always exists in a Jîva’s body. O Fair-eyed One! The effects of Prârabdha Karma, ripened and ready to yield their fruits must have to be experienced by a Jîva, whether happy or unhappy.**
>
> **Devi Bhagwatam 4:21**

One gets the birth as per their previous birth karma. **If someone is doing bad karmas and still he is enjoying pleasures it means he did many good karmas in previous birth.  When his good karmas exhausted, they had to suffer for their deeds.**

Comment: Upvote! Does Brihadaranyaka Upanishad talk of the law of Karma? Or which other Upanishads do?

Comment: @Archit I quoted a verse of Brihadarankya Upanishad related to karma. Do you want some verses?

Comment: No no thanks, just asking generally do other Upanishads talk of the law of karma in detail? And names of 1 or 2 main ones

Comment: The texts/rishis says that our suffering is due to karma, but they fail to look deeper into this matter OR clearly ignores the harsh fact that karma isn't really the ultimate cause of our miseries but there's something more powerful and sinister operating behind the worldly scenes, that manipulates our actions and forces us to act in certain ways ... IT controls us in such a way that we the common jivas often fail to use our buddhi (the judging/discriminating faculty inherent in our psyche.)

Comment: ... Because of this powerful sinister force which is working in the background and  constantly manipulating our thoughts, we end up doing deeds that often leads to our doom ... Our karma is NOT the ultimate cause of our suffering. Try to look a little deeper and you'll find out the source/origin (the root cause) of our ignorance and the actions that are born from it ... We're merely puppets here. We're hurled into this prison world so we could suffer and be a part of a sick play ... Karma is just an excuse that the Creator and his minions use in order to brush off "HIS" crimes under the rug.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a concept known as Prarabdh Karma.

As Swami Sivananda defines it -

> Prarabdha is that portion of the past karma which is responsible for the present body. That portion of the sanchita karma which influences human life in the present incarnation is called prarabdha. It is ripe for reaping. It cannot be avoided or changed. It is only exhausted by being experienced. You pay your past debts. Prarabdha karma is that which has begun and is actually bearing fruit. It is selected out of the mass of the sanchita karma.

Sanchita Karma are one of three types of Karma which follow through our births.

Take it this way, it is like our debts from our previous lives which we pay in our current life.And this type of Karma can't be avoided by any means as it can only be exhausted by experience.

Comment: Even if this karma is from past debts it seems odd that so many people in wealthy, influential and powerful positions are corrupt which brings down a cascading effect on everyone else's lives as well. The people in power must have done some good deeds in their past lives but they are clearly not born with virtue. So the good karma from the past creates an environment where they generate massively bad karma. It seems counter intuitive.

Comment: @Mugen Well I think this is due to Kali Yuga. In Bhagavata Purana it is clearly prophecised that in Kali Yuga the rulers will be corrupt. But Prarabdh Karma is also a reason for our current suffering.

Comment: But it seems we are not in Kali Yuga right now. Kali Yuga is over and we are in Dwapara Yuga. https://isha.sadhguru.org/in/en/wisdom/article/kali-yuga-end-lies-ahead

Comment: @Mugen I think SadhGuru is using the yuga theory given my sri yukteshwae giri in holy science. This theory is totally wrong and is contrary to itihas and purana. We are currently in Kali Yuga.

Comment: Questioner among other point is refering to individuals with material wealth and affluence indulging in reckless misdeeds  . Geeta ch 16 sloka 1-3 describes the  various attribute of  persons born with Daivi Sampad (  Divine State)  . Someone's trait like indulgence in reckless misdeeds by flaunting wealth is not among the divine attributes mentioned in the shloka above rather they have been declared demonic , the negative traits( ch 16 sl 8-21)Scripture clearly tell that a person with good past Karma is born with divine attributes and not with negative character traits. Indulgent one no PEACE

Comment: @Mugen, RishX is right. We are currently in year 5121 of Kali. It will last 4,32,000 years, so 4,27,000 years remaining, after which Satya (aka Krita) Yuga will begin again.

Comment: @ram Doesn't make sense to me. The real dark ages are behind us. In the age of kings the people would be killed in masses. We now have everything in civilization documented and we study these things via newspapers and in schools. If you see going back to 400-600BC those times were the true dark ages where we have little to no documentation and people constantly died of wars or diseases. One will have to be a pessimist to not see how well off we are in this age even with all the problems of modern life. Also, Mayan calendar has ended in 2012 after which the decline starts. 432k is ridiculous.