# What is karma as described in the Upanishads and in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, karma, upanishads

To my understanding karma is what you get when you don't do dharma.

I want to understand this with the example of Krishna, the very embodiment of dharma.

What did he do to get such seemingly bad karma, (being cursed and his sons killing each other)
Did he do something adharmic  in his past life, or up until the age of 16 when his guru's guru revealed to him what his destiny was?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly does karma work?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-exactly-does-karma-work)

Comment: No. I am interested only in references and deductions from the uphanishades and the mahabarata, and specifically how it applies in the example of Krishna.

Comment: The first line "To my understanding karma is what you get when you don't do dharma." is not true. You also get karma when you do dharma (i.e. act according to dharma). That karma is called good karma or punya @ArcDDD

Comment: This doesn't render the statement untrue. If don't do dharma you get karma. This is true. Now do you get karma (positive) if you do dharma I don't know, and I am only interested in explanations based directly on uphanishades or mahabharata.