# Why many good people suffer during death?

Tags: karma, death, destiny

Lord jesus, pitamah bhisma (mahapurush), our freedom fighters, army officers, many leaders in the history, many warrior in the past war, ........ - had death by tremendous suffering. NOW, the IMPORTANT thing is what GOD promised about good & bad karma - JUDGEMENT DAY is the most important - Death is not the result of KARMA - God promise that I'll send u heaven for good karma & I'll send u in hell for bad karma (u may reborn as an animal/insect/.......horrible human life, hole life is intolerable suffering & curse). 'if we live, we live for the God, and if we die, we die for the God' - who gave me birth? I? u? God gave, who will take my life? I? U? God will - so we'll return back to Him and then He will judge our KARMA - Neither I nor u but God will give him reward. See one counter example - look at politician & other criminals - are they get horrible death? Most of the times no - but that is not end, that is why I tell u about judgement day.  "Just as it is appointed for man to die once and after that face to judgement (either to heaven or to hell). Death is appointed, and you are no exception. You only die once, and death is not the end; it is your destiny's door." - Hebrews 9:27 (Bible). U know that like us animals are child of God - then why do u eat mutton? Let me try to clear your confusion/dilemma - Death is not the result of KARMA, Death/Birth is pre-written destiny. Consider the example of Thakur Ramakrishna - u know that he died by throat cancer & he had to suffer a lot of pain. Now u tell me was he a bad man? was it the result of his good karma? Do u heard about child death? Children are innocent, how they die? Recently I've heard a story in my locality - a child of age 3 was riding on the scooty with her elder sister of age 12. The little child just crushed by a truck. Now u tell me what bad karma that little child has done? Was it her reward for bad karma?

Comment: Karma isn't accumulated in an hour or a day, it's carried forward throughout different births. You can get more insight about karma in this question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/138/11875

Comment: Anyone who is born has to suffer as earthly realm is of mortals, even Gods or avatars suffers from past births Karmas, except the true Self Brahman every thing with a form and motion is temporary. https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/ "BG 2.27: Death is certain for one who has been born, and rebirth is inevitable for one who has died. Therefore, you should not lament over the inevitable."

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE! Kindly have a look at the [HSE HELP CENTER](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help), **specifically** the [How does New User get Started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se) and also, [HSE FAQ INDEX](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange). Please go through them and get started in here properly. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: You can see this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33090/4732